# Why are parts of the output overwritten when redirected to the same file but not when to terminal?

Tags: c, bash, file-io, stdout, file-descriptor

I want to be able to output to both stdout(&stderr) AND to another file (log file) without worrying that the log file would get corrupted output for the case when shell is redirecting stdout(and/or stderr) to the same log file.

For my particular case, I've tried checking the stat bits(`man 2 stat`) for stdout and for the log file, in order to determine that they point to the same device and inode, in which case don't fopen() the log file but instead fopen() the stdout file, for writing to the log file.
Exactly what I mean(`.c` code): https://github.com/libcheck/check/issues/188#issuecomment-492852881
This works as a workaround.

Here's a .c code example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE *f=NULL;
  f = fopen("/tmp/a_out_.log", "w");
  if (NULL == f) {
    fprintf(stderr,"oopsie\n");
  } else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Something");
    fprintf(f," messy ");
    fprintf(f," jessy\n");
    fprintf(stdout, " or another\n");
    fprintf(f,"More stuff\n");
    fclose(f);                                                                                                                  
  }
}
```

Run like this(from `bash`) to see the overwritten output:

```
$ gcc a.c && { ./a.out >/tmp/a_out_.log ; cat /tmp/a_out_.log ; }
Something or another
uff
```

I've simplified the `.c` code and reduced it to a bash lines, but the functionality (ie. garbled output) is illustrated just the same:

All of these show correct output:

```sh
(echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" ; echo "blah" >&2)
(echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" ; echo "blah" >&2) 1>/tmp/good 2>&1 ; cat /tmp/good
(echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" ; echo "blah" >&2) 1>/dev/stdout 2>/dev/stdout
(echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" ; echo "blah" >&2) 1>/proc/self/fd/1 2>/proc/self/fd/1
(echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" ; echo "blah" >&2) 1>/proc/self/fd/2 2>/proc/self/fd/2
```

output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
blah
```

But, the following one shows overwritten output:

```sh
(echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" ; echo "blah" >&2) 1>/tmp/bad 2>/tmp/bad; cat /tmp/bad
```

(the corrupted)output looks like:

```
blah
 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Real world example of where this is happening(with reproduction steps even): https://github.com/libcheck/check/issues/188

Comment: Both the program and the shell (though the redirection) are writing to the same file simultaneously! That won't work very well (as you noticed). What are you really trying to do? Why are you redirecting to the same file as the program is writing to? What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You can replace `file` with `terminal`(in what you said) and for that it works, why? Real problem? use same log file for this case https://github.com/libcheck/check/issues/188

Comment: It shouldn't be the program's responsibility to work around user mistakes. This is UNIX, after all. If the user does something foolish that's their problem, not yours. Let them remove the problematic redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are parts of the output overwritten when redirected to the same
>   file but not when on terminal?

Because you have the file open twice, *separately*, on a regular file, in ordinary write mode.  Each open file description for that file has its own sense of the current file position, and that's where the data it writes go.  Each file position advances only in accordance with the data written via the corresponding open file description.  Whichever data happens to be written second at a given position replaces what was written first.

This does not happen for a terminal, because terminals are not seekable.  It's as if they are always open in append mode.  Opening your log file in append mode would provide half of a solution, and would be a good idea in any case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE *f=NULL;
  f = fopen("/tmp/a_out_.log", "a");  // <-- here is the change
  if (NULL == f) {
    fprintf(stderr,"oopsie\n");
  } else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Something");
    fprintf(f," messy ");
    fprintf(f," jessy\n");
    fprintf(stdout, " or another\n");
    fprintf(f,"More stuff\n");
    fclose(f);                                                                                                                  
  }
}
```

That way, writes to file `f` always go to the current end of file, regardless of what may have been done to the file by other means.  If you want an existing log file to be truncated, however, then you'll have to do that yourself, unlike when you open in write (`"w"`) mode.

As I said, however, although opening in append mode is probably a good idea in this case regardless, it's only half a solution.  If the standard output is open on the same file, separately, in regular write mode, then writes from that direction still can and will overwrite other output.  Frankly, I'd be inclined to say that **that should not be your program's concern**.  If the user *really* wants to redirect the program's console output to its log file, then it is within their power to do so in append mode, by using the `>>` redirection operator instead of `>`.  That would constitute the complement of the above half solution.  If they use a `>` redirection instead then that's on them, and I would not go to extraordinary measures to detect or accommodate it.

Comment: Could you think of a case where `cmd > file` is better than the equivalent of doing `: > file ; cmd >> file` if it was done under the hood by the same command? ie. if `cmd > file` did that(create&truncate file, then redirect to it in append mode) instead, under the hood? In other words, why doesn't `cmd > file` do THAT already?

Comment: @howaboutsynergy, the `>` operator does not open the file in append mode because *there's another operator for that*.  Additionally, the three basic redirection operators, `<`, `>`, and `>>` map nicely onto the three unidirectional open modes of `fopen()`, `"r"`, `"w"`, and `"a"`.  That opening in append mode does not first truncate the file seems natural to me; I don't know whether there is any deeper reason than that.

Comment: Adding `O_APPEND` to bash code responsible for `>` seems to work so far, no more overwrites even with fopen() `"w"`; the bash code is in `./make_cmd.c` function `make_redirection`, line is `temp->flags = O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY | O_CREAT;` initially! [discussion?](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-05/msg00041.html) So, can you (or anyone) think of any good reason why O_APPEND shouldn't be there? (genuinely want to know!) PS: `<>` is handled separately(just below, in their code).

Comment: I'm sorry @howaboutsynergy, are you seriously proposing that `bash`'s behavior be changed?  Although that should be technically *feasible*, it would render `bash` non-conforming.  You have a mechanism for achieving the result you want with unmodified `bash`.

Comment: But it would be functionally the same, would it not? except that it "fixes" the overwriting issue. So it's more like a bugfix, imho :) But then again I'm not a developer...

Comment: No, @howaboutsynergy, it would *not* be functionally the same.  If it were, then there wouldn't be any point.  You may find the shell's behavior *surprising* in this area, but it is not *buggy*.  On the contrary, you are proposing to **introduce** a bug.

Comment: My conclusion so far: https://github.com/libcheck/check/issues/188#issuecomment-493423488

Comment: @howaboutsynergy, I agree -- and indeed, wrote in this answer -- that it makes sense to open log files in append mode.  I strongly *dis*agree that it should be standard practice for programs to truncate their log files at startup.  No doubt it makes sense for some programs to do so, but it makes at least as much sense for other programs to avoid doing so.  Furthermore, I remind you again that the overwriting issue you observed is a function of the same file being opened multiple times concurrently, and only if all handles on it are in append mode are overwrites reliably avoided.